# Can Java Validator method validateProperty validate object with multiple fields inside?

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

As stated in the title, I'm using the Validator to validate fields based on their names like this:

```
 mandatoryInputs.stream()
            .map(x -> v.validateProperty(accountBenefitForm, x, AccountBenefitFormAdditionalInfo.class))
```

it works fine, but only for the simple fields like Strings that have their constraints in the accountBenefitForm for example:

```
@NotBlank(message = "Username can not be null.", groups = {AccountBenefitFormBasicInfo.class})
@Size(max = 255, message = "Username is too long (max size 255).")
private String username;
```

But it won't work for objects that have multiple fields inside them, like this one:

```
@Valid
private ContactData contactData;
```

where ContactData implementation looks like this:

```
@NotBlank(message = "You have to add e-mail address.", groups = {AccountBenefitFormAdditionalInfo.class})
@Email(message = "E-mail is not valid.", groups = {AccountBenefitFormAdditionalInfo.class})
@Size(max = 255, message = "E-mail is too long (max size 255).", groups = {AccountBenefitFormAdditionalInfo.class})
private String email;

@NotBlank(groups = {AccountBenefitFormAdditionalInfo.class})
private String phoneNumber;
```

Is there a way I can make this work or do I need to validate those more complex objects on their own?

Answer (score 2):

You have basically two kinds of annotations that can be used for validations here: Spring annotations (`@Validated`) as well as the javax annotation (`@Valid`, `@NotBlank`) etc.

For Spring, you can luckily often skip the manual validation unless you have some custom constraints (e.g. if person lives in country ABC, they need to provide additional info). Annotating just the field is not enough if you don't cascade the validation from the outer class. This cascade can be done conveniently on method-level by annotating the method param with `@Valid` e.g.

```
void doSomething(@Valid ContactDataHolder contactDataHolder) { ... }
```

If you'd like to use validation in Spring, I would recommend to use the Spring Validator interface instead of the one from javax as it should give you the expected behavior for nesting. You might also decide to apply `@Validated` on the class level to save you from writing `@Valid(ated)` on the method level each time.

Comment: I mean that's what I'm trying to do, I just don't know if I can somehow use the validator like I've shown to enter the contactData field to validate its fields or I just need to run a separate loop like that: 
`v.validateProperty(accountBenefitForm.getContactData(), x, AccountBenefitFormAdditionalInfo.class))`

Comment: Also, `@Valid` actually is part of javax which comes from jsr-303 standard, just like `@NotBlank` and such. `@Validated` is a Spring annotation

Comment: You're right, from my memory I thought that Spring had it's own `@Valid` annotation. I'll edit this asap. If you don't have constraints that cannot be expressed through the jsr-303 annotations, then you can call `@Valid` on a method argument and you don't need to initialize a Validator. So if you use the object holding `@Valid ContactData` it would look like `void doSomething(@Valid ContactDataHolder contactDataHolder) { ... }`.

Comment: The thing is I don't know which fields will need to be validated at compile time. The list of fields that needs validation is dynamic and stored in database, that's why `object.validateProperty`  comes in handy. But I don't know if it is possible to make validateProperty cascade the validation like you normally do when annotating the method parameter and the field that needs cascading

Comment: I think I've actually just found the solution to my problem:
[CascadingPropertyValidator docs](https://bval.apache.org/mvnsite/apidocs/org/apache/bval/jsr/CascadingPropertyValidator.html)

I'll test it and post as answer if it's all good

Answer (score 0):

So I've managed to somewhat resolve my problem by using the Apache BVal. Heres the code to create a validator to use the `validateProperty` method with cascading validation enabled:

`ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.byProvider(ApacheValidationProvider.class).configure().buildValidatorFactory();`

`CascadingPropertyValidator validator = factory.getValidator().unwrap(CascadingPropertyValidator.class);`

`validator.validateProperty(accountBenefitForm, x, true, Default.class, AccountBenefitFormAdditionalInfo.class))`

where x is the string of field to validate, and if that field is annotated with @Valid, it will then validate the inside fields according to their own constraints.

Along the way I've also found out that you can just use the "normal" javax Validator and pass the field to validate as `contactData.email` which means validate `email` field of the `contactData` field of the object that u pass as first argument to the `validateProperty` method.

Edit:
BVal supports Bean Validation 1.1 (JSR 349) and not the 2.0 version(JSR 380), and since `@NotBlank` or `@NotEmpty` constrains are part of 2.0, it won't validate a field annotated with them. Here are the docs for the [1.1](https://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#builtinconstraints) , and [2.0](https://beanvalidation.org/2.0-jsr380/spec/#builtinconstraints)